# List differences between numbers

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7

I have seconds input ordered data from smallest to largest for both times.

```
 start_time[s] = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 61, 79, 80]

 end_time[s] = [8, 9, 15, 31, 41, 60]
```

The lists are not the same sizes as they are generated log file timestamp data

I want to get output for the positive difference between end_time and the minimum of the start_time

The code I have is as follows:

```
  for item1 in end_time:   
    for item2 in start_time:  
      if (item1 > item2):
         new_item = item1 - item2
         new_list.append(new_item)
```

> > > [5, 21, 11, 1, 31, 21, 11, 1, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10]

The ideal output will be generated as follows:

> > > [5, 11, 11, 20]

5...this is by taking the end_time of 15 - the start_time of 10, why? Its the first   end_time > start_time (8,9 are also end_times less than 10)

11...this is by taking the next end_time of 31 (i don't want to use 15 as i will be double counting) and then subract the next start_time of 20 to give 11.

11...this is by taking the following end_time of 41 and subtracting the start_time of 30 to give 11.

20...this will be the last entry, it takes the 60 from the end_time and uses 40 from the start_time to give a difference of 20.

Comment: How does the input relate to the output?

Comment: The inputs are two different hh:mm:ss time stamps that I have converted into seconds. So the L1 is equivalent to the start time and the L2 is equivalent to the end time.

Comment: ... But they're not even the same length...

Comment: Your code is not correct (e.g. `if (L1 < L2)` ...)

Comment: I made additional edits to try and clarify my problem- i have also made the L1, L2 changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that both lists are in order, which is what your sample data shows.

```
timeDeltas = []
idxStart = 0
idxEnd =  len(end_time)
for start in start_time:
    for i in range(idxStart, idxEnd)
        delta = 0
        end = end_time[i]
        if end > start:
            delta = end - start
            idxStart = i
        else:
            timeDeltas.append(delta)
            break
```

Note that I have no sanity checking (e.g. the same end time could be used over and over).

Comment: Ideally i would like to only use one end_time value for each calculation and cycle through both the end_time and start_time lists

Comment: Updated to reflect what you suggested; I haven't tested it, but I think it should work

Comment: I realized with a fresh perspective that I was over-complicating things for myself. So i re-examined how I was obtaining the timestamp data and found better search strings that provide me with an ideal output. I do appreciate your insight on the nested loops that I will definitely use for other programs.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i did it

```
start_time = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 61, 79, 80]
end_time = [8, 9, 15, 31, 41, 60]
time_difference = [(min(start_time) - et) for et in end_time if min(start_time) > et]
[2,1]
```

Your question maybe a bit ambiguous. I assume you strictly want positive time differences.

What is the output that you would like?

Comment: I have made additional revisions- to try and capture the problem.